# How many spanning trees of $K_9$ have exactly one vertex of degree 5?

Tags: combinatorics, trees, graph-laplacian

Given the complete graph $K_9$, how would you find the number of spanning trees that have exactly one vertex with degree 5?
I am a first-year student studying CS. This question was discussed in our Discrete Maths class.

I tried solving it by making one vertex fixed and it has a degree of 5 which could be 5 other vertices and I am left with 3 vertices. Then I applied (8 choose 3) on various scenarios but couldn't come to a proper answer.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @AnotherUser is right about what’s expected here before one posts and about the things posts should demonstrate.

Comment: Sure @PaulTanenbaum , this is my first post here and would take it in consideration next time.

Comment: HINT: Look at your single degree-5 vertex and its neighbors. Some things to consider: How many more edges are there between those first $1+5$ vertices? How many more vertices are there left to account for? How might they be joined into the tree?

Comment: What is $8\choose 3$ about your problem?

Comment: 8 choose 3 are the number of ways by which the remaining 3 vertices can be chosen. If I fix  one vertex and give it a degree of 5, then I am using 6 vertices, so 3 more vertices are left to account for which are given by (8 choose 3)

Comment: Choosing your degree-5 vertex can be done in $9 \choose 1$ way, which leaves $8 \choose 5$ ways to pick its neighbors. And at that point there is only $3\choose 3$ way to pick the remaining 3 vertices that require joining in to the tree.

Comment: True, if I take this into account and multiply these 3 values I get 504 possible spanning trees, but that will include duplicates, I suppose

Comment: There are various ways that any triple of remaining vertices can be joined in. Since it’s a spanning **tree**, the only constraint is that as you join them in, you must not create any cycles.

Comment: What are you seeing some of your duplicates’ looking like?

Comment: I mean isomorphic spanning trees.

Comment: If you’re working with unlabeled graphs, then the number of possible spanning trees is very small indeed. And your 504 becomes 1.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the vertex of degree 5 (call it A) and its 5 neighbours (call them B, C, D, E, F). 3 more vertices are then going to be attached to B, C, D, E, F.

First, suppose that all 3 remaining vertices are connected to the same vertex, say B (connected possibly via other two, but not through A). How many ways are there to do it?

Second, suppose that two of the remaining 3 vertices are connected to B and one to C. How many ways are there to do it?

Third, explore other options (there are not many of them).

Sum the counts to get the answer.